# Facebook Post Publishing without any Dialogue using Javascript SDK

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have been searching for facebook publishing without showing Dialogue.
While reading Facebook developers doc, there are several things which seems to answer the question but after using them, I concluded those are not for this functionality.

1. Display Modes: They are different type of display mode for dialogues, but there is no way to define if I don't want to show the dialogue.
2. Explicit Sharing: This seems to be most close. But there is no way to use it in JS SDK. And the parameter mentioned there, I tried in JS but no resolution.

Then here what came to be most successful for me, to use

> methode: '/me/feed'

But the problem is, it says:

> [User] shared a link

Which I don't want. I want a normal publishing, but without any dialogue to be displayed.

Code I am using for simple publishing is below:

```
function publishNewsFeed(picURL, name, caption, description)
{
    var obj = 
    {
      method: 'feed',
      link: fbAppURL,
      picture: picURL,
      name: name,
      caption: caption,
      description: description
    };
    function callback(response) 
    {
      document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Post ID: " + response['post_id'];
    }          

    FB.ui(obj, callback);
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks
-WI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Display Modes: They are different type of display mode for dialogues, but there is no way to define if I don't want to show the dialogue.

That would be nonsense – if you don’t want to *use* a dialog, then don’t use a dialog.

But if you want to use a dialog, then it has to be “shown” in some way – otherwise it *would not be* a dialog.

> But the problem is, it says *[User] shared a link* Which I don't want.

That is current “bug” – if you supply action links with your post, it will show up normal.

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/485696594791863

Comment: "if you don’t want to use a dialog, then don’t use a dialog." That's my point, I believe the only way to publish from JS SDK is the one I shared. And it always open a popup. Can I achieve this, i.e. while not using dialogs, publish my post using JS SDK?

Comment: well I just tried FB.api, and now no popup, but no post on my wall as well. I tried this: 
function publishNewsFeed(picURL, name, caption, description)
{

 var obj = 
 {
  method: 'stream.publish',
  link: fbAppURL,
  picture: picURL,
  name: name,
  caption: caption,
  description: description,
  actions: {name:"Test Waqar", link: "some url"}
 };
 FB.api('/me/feed', 'POST', publish, function(response) {  
     document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Post ID: " + response['post_id'];
  });
}

Comment: Ok I got it successfully implemented by using:  
FB.api('/me/feed', 'POST', obj, 
        function(response) 
 {  document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Post ID: " + response['post_id'];
 });

     But the problem now is, it says: "Waqar Iqbal shared a link via App Name." But I want as standard feed, not a shared link.
What I am missing?

Comment: _“What I am missing?”_ – my original answer …

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much for your help. I did applied the same thing specified on your mentioned link before too, but the only thing which make it worked is "message" parameter. Though I have no idea why, when not providing message parameter, it doesn't work. Anyways, thanks a lot. :)

Comment: I must specify for other users: FP.api('/me/feed', 'post', params, callBackFunction); allows you to post on facebook wall without showing a dialogue. Also if providing link gives the output, [username] shared a link using [app name], then read the link CBroe mentioned in his original link. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function jesseSays(){
    var body = 'Yeah science Mr. White!!';
    FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { 
      message: body,
      link: 'http://www.neoapps.com.br',
      picture: 'http://www.neoapps.com.br/assets/img/logo-big.png'
    }, function(response) {
      if (!response || response.error) {
        alert('Error occured');
      } else {
        alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
      }
    });
  }
```